# Only first word of two strings gets added to db

Tags: android

When trying to add words to a database via php, only the first word of both strings gets added.

I send the text via this code:

```
public void sendTextToDB() {

valcom = editText1.getText().toString();
valnm = editText2.getText().toString(); 

t = new Thread() {
public void run() {
try {
url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/HB/hikebuddy.php?function=setcomm&comment="+valcom+"&name="+valnm);
h = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

if( h.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
is = h.getInputStream();
}else{
is = h.getErrorStream();
}

h.disconnect();

} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
Log.d("Test", "CONNECTION FAILED 1");
}
}
};

t.start();

}
```

When tested with spaces and commas etc. in a browser, the php function adds all text.
The strings also return the full value when inserted into a dialog.

How do I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URL-encode `valcom` and `valnm` when putting them into the URL.

See `java.net.URLEncoder.encode`: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html

```
url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2/HB/hikebuddy.php?function=setcomm&comment="
              + URLEncoder.encode(valcom)
              + "&name="+ URLEncoder.encode(valnm));
```

Comment: You may also consider passing this data via POST rather than GET.